# how can i find the source code of a chip/piece of hardware?

Tags: reverse-engineering, exploit

I was wondering: how can i analize the source code of a chip or any programmed piece of hardware? for example people who managed to find a 0day in the old version of nintendo switch; how did they find the code to analyze and find the bug? i would really like to get involved i 0days or reversing, and also would like to, i dont know, for example find an exploit/ a bug in my own home router/ in my calculator and stuff like that. I think knowing how the hardware is coded and how it works and have control on it is much more interesting than high level stuff.

I googled something but did not manage to get any information, maybe i'm just not enough good at googling :\

sorry if it may sound like a dummy question but i do not know very much about it.

Comment: Chips don't have source code.  They have operation codes (or opcodes) that are specific to a specific chip architecture.  As one example, here is one academic explanation of the [Intel x86 architecture](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html).